# Two Part Question Regarding Function Analysis and Encryption

Tags: data-analysis

I've been to my professors office hours, and my teaching assistants are not making this clear for me. Encryption is such a great field of study and I really would like to get off on the right foot. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Two part question:

Communication security is extremely important in computer networks, and one way many network protocols achieve security is to encrypt messages. Typical cryptographic schemes for the secure transmission of messages over such networks are based on the fact that no efficient algorithms are known for factoring large integers. Hence, if we can represent a secret message by a large prime number p, we can transmit, over the network, the number r=p*q, where q>p is another large prime number that acts as the encryption key. An eavesdropper who obtains the transmitted number r on the network would have to factor r in order to figure out the secret message p. Using factoring to figure out a message is very difficult without knowing the encryption key q. To understand why, consider the following naive factoring algorithm:

```
for p=2,...,r-1 do 
if p divides r then 
    return “The secret message is p!”
```

(a) Suppose that the eavesdropper uses the above algorithm and has a computer that can carry out in 1 microsecond (1 millionth of a second) a division between two integers of up to 100 bits each. Give an estimate of the time that it will take in the worst case to decipher the secret message p if the transmitted message r has 100 bits.

I was told that 0 <= r <= (2^100)-1. Where did 2^100 come from?

If I then know that r = (2^100)-1, then this should represent the worst case running time. So r*10^-6 (us) should equal total running time. Correct?

(b) What is the worst-case time complexity of the above algorithm? Since the input to the algorithm is just one large number r, assume that the input size n is the number of bytes needed to store r, that is, n=floor(log_{2}r)/8)+1, and that each division takes time O(n)

I need further clarification on what this asking. The wording is really not making this obvious to me.

Comment: For (a): how many different messages of 100 bits are there? And part b just asks that in the worst case (i.e. the loop runs as long as possible) how much time will it take?

Comment: a)One bit is two values, so 2^100?

Comment: b)(n(n-1))/2? @tabstop

Comment: a) Yes, so now you know where $2^{100}$ comes from. For part b, look at how many times your loop will run.

Comment: So solving for r we get, r=2^(8n).

f(n)=2n^(8n) Multiplying by an additional n since each division is O(n). Therefore worst case is O(n^n)? @tabstop

Comment: There's a difference between $n\times 2^n$ and $(2n)^n$.

Comment: I don't know...